# How to customize Nebular component style if it is not mapped to a theme variable

Tags: nebular

I know how to change the theme variables to customize a component but, what should I do when there is no theme variable to change?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**
If you want to edit card-border-width, then just edit it the same way you would edit the theme variables.

```
card-border-width: 0;
```

**Long answer**
Think of *Name* and *Theme variables* as scss variables, programming wise there's really no hierarchy as they can be edited and combined in any ways.
Take card-text-color for instance.

```
text-basic-color: #222b45;
card-text-color: text-basic-color;
```

Now if you would like to change the card-text-color, could edit either text-basic-color or card-text-color for the same result. Change card-text-color if you only want this settings to be applied to cards. Change text-basic-color if you want to all components (the whole theme) to inherit the color. In the case of card-border-width, there is not theme variable so just edit card-border-width.